# Why The character is showing like rotated '?'

Tags: objective-c, properties, char

My project is to make Checker turkish game

and i made 2 classes Board and Cell

in Cell.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Cell : NSObject

{
    int number;
    char checker;
}
@property (nonatomic ) int number;
@property (nonatomic ) char checker;
@end
```

and in Cell.m

```
#import "Cell.h"

@implementation Cell
-(void)Cell{
    checker=' ';
    number=1;
}
@end
```

but in board.m I tried many ways but the didnt success 
here is my code to print out the checker

```
DrawCell[ 3 ].checker  = 'X';
```

and the result is rotated question mark 
also the numbers all of them are 0 and i am trying to change them but they stell 0

thanks

Comment: Probably the sideways question mark is some "unprintable" character, due either to generating the wrong character code or due to having the wrong character set translation defined.

Comment: But note you don't tell us how DrawCell is defined or what you do with it's contents.  (One might suppose that DrawCell is a pointer to an instance of Cell, but surely that's not the case since, by standard Objective-C conventions, variables should begin with a lower case letter, while classes begin with upper-case.)

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation showing a method `Cell` suggests you might come from C++ where a constructor is named after the class. Objective-C does this differently. The implementation which matches your `@interface` is:

```
@implementation Cell

@synthesize number, checker; // implement the properties, not required in Xcode 4.4

- (id) init // the constructor
{
   self = [super init]; // must invoke superclass init
   if(self != nil)      // check a valid object reference was returned
   {
      checker = ' ';
      number = 1;
   }
   return self;         // return the initialized object
}

@end
```

Now it looks like you are declaring a static array `DrawCell` of `Cell *`, something like:

```
Cell *DrawCell[9];
```

You need to allocate the cells in this array, a loop can do that:

```
for(unsigned ix = 0; ix < 9; ix++)
   DrawCell = [[Cell alloc] init]; // allocate & init each Cell
```

Now your line:

```
DrawCell[3].checker = 'X';
```

should work fine.

Some might suggest that you use an `NSArray` rather than a C-style array, but in your case of a small fixed-sized array  the latter is fine.

Others might suggest you don't even bother with an object for this as you appear to be only storing two simple pieces of data. Using a structure in this case could be a good choice, e.g. use:

```
typedef struct
{
   int number;
   char checker;
} Cell;

Cell DrawCell[9];
```

and your line

```
DrawCell[3].checker = 'X';
```

also works and there is no need for dynamic memory allocation, property synthesis, etc.

HTH